# How can I use Vite to create a simple (one file) Typescript NPM package?

Tags: typescript, npm, vite, npm-publish

I would like to create a small open-source library and register it with NPM so that I can use it in my other projects. What is the best way to do this with Vite?
The library is pretty simple, it is a one file of Typescript. Ideally I just need to be able to:

1. Compile with typescript
2. Run tests (any testing framework as long as it is simple)
3. Package and deploy NPM package

Is there perhaps a simple (as in as few files as possible) template or some other way (maybe a blog post) that you would recommend?
Note: I've tried doing this with `npm create vite@latest` --> `Vanilla` --> `Typescript`. However this creates `index.html` and bunch of other files which I really do not need.  I would really like to keep it as simple as possible, I'm not interested in minification, tree-shaking ... kitchen sink etc. My library is pretty simple and only needs basic Javascript functionality, it does not use any browser (DOM) or node.js functionality.

Thanks in advance for any helpful reply.

Comment: I have a starter template: https://github.com/jasonsturges/vite-typescript-npm-package